# ffmpeg How does the blend filter work

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have small project which uses blend filter of FFmpeg library.

I read the examples of this document
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend_002c-tblend

But I'm not clearly understand about it.

> X, Y : the coordinates of the current sample
>
> W, H : the width and height of currently filtered plane

What are the sample and filtered plane?
Is there any document about these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of an image, a sample refers to an individual pixel. However, a pixel usually has multiple components, like RGB (red, green and blue) or YUV (luma and two chroma units). So 'sample' here refers to the individual stores of value, i.e. a Magenta RGB pixel is defined by three samples `(255,0,255)`.

Pixels of a frame can be stored packed (`R1G1B1R2G2B2..`) or planar (`[R1R2...RN][G1G2..GN][B1B2..BN]`). The blend filter works on planar formats only.

In YUV format images, the UV is typically [subsampled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) and so the width and height of UV planes is lower than that of the luma plane.

Comment: 1/ Are there any relationship between the width and height of these planes and image's size.

2/ If  UV planes's size is lower than luma plane, how can they composed into 1 frame, and X Y are coordinates of either luma's sample or chroma's sample.

3/ Is there any document or book talking these things in detail?

Comment: Luma plane size is the same as the image size. Typically, the ratio of luma plane dimension to chroma plane dimension is a power of two (1,2,4...). There are many books on the matter. Start with the wiki link and explore. See the citations in those articles for sources.

Comment: thank for your reply @Gyan, I have another question, ffmpeg will extract input files (A, B)  into planes then blend Ay with By, Au with Bu, Av with Bv, and compose them, isn't it.

Comment: Can I have your skype or email ?

Comment: @Gyan From where do you know that the `blend` filter only works with planar inputs? I couldn't find anything about this in `ffmpeg -help filter=blend` or on ffmpeg.org.

Comment: Its not documented. You have to examine the source.